# Texture Editing with Multi-Threading

Tags: xna, c#, multithreading

So I have this giant Texture2D (4096 * 4096, don't ask why) and all its data stored in an array of Colors. When I hit left MouseButton I create a blue 64 by 64 square at the cursor's position using the following code.

```
        int dx = Mouse.GetState().X + (int)camera.Pos.X - graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2;
        int dy = Mouse.GetState().Y + (int)camera.Pos.Y - graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2;

        for (int x = dx; x < dx + 64; x++)
        {
            for (int y = dy; y < dy + 64; y++)
            {
                textureData[x + y * texture.Width] = Color.Blue;
            }
        }

        texture.SetData<Color>(lvlData);
```

Sadly this hangs the program for a split second. So I thought, maybe it's possible to run that piece of code in a different thread.

Is it possible to multi-thread that and if so, how would I go about doing that? Or is it another way to optimize this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: it is highly unlikely that the lag is caused by your loop, the only thing that could cause this lag is uploading the texture to your gpu, you might want to lay that out to another thread. I would advise you to use multiple small textures so that re-uploading doesn't cause such long pauses.

Comment: As VaTTeRGeR said, your best option is to split the image out into several smaller textures, and draw each of them separately. If you don't specifically need to set the pixels on the texture, I recommend drawing a separate 64x64 texture on top of this 4096x4096 image instead of manipulating the pixels on the actual texture.

Answer (score 2):

Setting data in the texture is an expensive operation at that resolution size. It should be avoided if you plan to do that every frame.

I don't know why you want to set the data in the source image like that, but for the texture there are a couple of options:

If you just want the blue square at the current mouse position:

1. Draw the texture to the screen and then draw a blue square where the mousecursor is.
2. Alternatively, create a `RenderTarget2D`; draw the texture and then draw the blue square to the rendertarget.

If you want to blue squares as if they were "painted" (thus not removed, which is what I gather from the code you posted):

3. Create a `RenderTarget2D` that isn't cleared between frames- that is use the `RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents` flag when creating the rendertarget, draw the blue square to the rendertarget whenever the mousebutton is clicked.
4. Keep a list of mouseclicks and draw the blue squares in a spritebatch after you draw the texture to the screen.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely sounds like a render target is what should be used in this case unless I'm reading the question wrong.